# Join Statement doesn't allow data to be collected on the foreign key?

Tags: php, mysql

When I make a join statement on two columns on two data tables one of the data tables stops collecting data. Table 1 is called users which has the column idUsers (reference key). Table 2 is called user_classes which has the column id (foreign key). user_classes stops collecting data. If I switch the relationship, the same thing happens but reversed. I'm very confused as to why this happens, could someone please explain in the comments? Or perhaps offer a solution?

```
SELECT user_classes.id, users.idUsers FROM users JOIN user_classes ON user_classes.id = users.idUsers;
```

**//Insert Code for table "users"**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (uidUsers, emailUsers, pwdUsers) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";


$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror7");
        exit();
    }
```

**//Insert Code for table "user_classes"**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_classes(class1, class2, class3, class4, class5, class6, class7, class8) VALUES ('$class1', '$class2', '$class3', '$class4', '$class5', '$class6', '$class7', '$class8');";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
header("Location:../hours.php?next=success");
```

[image: Img 1 is the users table]

[image: Img 2 is the user_classes table]

[image: Img 3 shows the relationship (idUsers is the reference key, id is the foreign key]

Comment: Can you show some sample data? I do not think your idUsers are same as id in user_classses. Secondly... where are the columns? you have table names in select, instead of columns

Comment: What do you mean "stops collecting data"?

Comment: @NawedKhan I posted a few photos. If you'll notice, the numbers in table 2 are blue because of the relationship I created between them. So when I click on id 1 for example, it brings me up to the user "Nick" from the other table.

Comment: @Uueerdo What I mean is, if you look at the photos above notice how there are several idUsers- that is me attempting to create new accounts via a login system I made. However, look at how after I made the relationship and used my SQL query, none of those user accounts appear in the second table. Hence only the first 2 users are recorded in the data table, because I made those accounts before running the query and making the relationship.

Comment: `SELECT user_classes, users` makes no sense. You're supposed to list column names after `SELECT`, not table names. Did you mean `SELECT user_classes.*, users.*`?

Comment: You should normalize your `user_classes` table. There should be a separate row for each class, not 8 column.

Comment: The query works for me: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fg9cWA2mR4Zzq9ZnXgKSH4/1 Just selecting the IDs doesn't return anything useful, though.

Comment: @Barmar Yes that's what I meant to type, my mistake. I'll have to look more into the concept of normalizing but, could you please explain the benefit of doing so and how that'd provide a solution? Or affect the problem?

Comment: It makes writing queries easier, since you don't have to list 8 columns to get all the classes. For instance, if you want to find all the students taking CS, you would have to write `WHERE 'CS' in (class1, class2, class3, ...)` instead of just `WHERE class = 'CS'`

Comment: @Barmar Alright, I'll have to look into that. It would certainly be useful for the future- thank you. Although, do you have any explanation as to why the data the user types when signing up isn't recorded depending on whatever the foreign key is? If I don't set a foreign key, the issue doesn't occur however I need the foreign key set in order to run the query and have a relation between the two tables. Is it possible that I need to restructure my query around the Join statement?

Comment: You'll have to show the code you're using to insert into the tables. I thought your question was about the `SELECT` query.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not running an insert statement from the MySQL database myself manually, but instead its inserted from a web page. I don't believe the issue is with my insert code though because if I delete the relationship between the two tables, all the data is inserted into the tables without errors.

Comment: We need to see that web page code. It's probably not filling in the foreign key correctly.

Comment: If you try to fill in `user_classes.id` incorrectly, you'll get a foreign key constraint violation error.

Comment: @Barmar Alright, I tried to paste very little code so that way you guys wouldn't have to be looking through so many lines in order to narrow down the problem. $conn is a variable that connects to the database, its declared in another file.

Comment: When you insert into `user_classes`, you don't fill in the `id` column, so it's not linked to the user whose classes you're setting.

Comment: @Barmar The id is an autoincremented int. Doesn't that mean I don't have to insert it? If I click on id 1 from the user_classes table, it brings me up to the corresponding user from the users table. In this case that'd be "Nick". If I do the reverse and switch the foreign key/reference key, the same is true. Doesn't that mean the ids are linked?

Comment: You can't use `auto_increment` for a foreign key. A foreign key has to be the same as the key of the related row in the referenced table, you can't assign it automatically.

Comment: You use auto increment when creating the ID in the `users` table, then copy that ID to the `user_classes` table.

Answer (score 0):

You're not filling in the `id` column in the `user_classes` table. It needs to be the ID that was assigned to the user when insert into the `users` table. The code should be something like this:

```
// Add the user
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (uidUsers, emailUsers, pwdUsers) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $uid, $email, $pwd);
$stmt->execute();
$idUser = $stmt->insert_id; // get the ID assigned to the user.
// Add the classes
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_classes(id, class1, class2, class3, class4, class5, class6, class7, class8) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("issssssss", $idUser, $class1, $class2, $class3, $class4, $class5, $class6, $class7, $class8);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I don't think that code specifically will work with my case, but the concept of what the issue is and how to solve it seems more clear. I don't want to close this yet though in case other people notice anything else that's wrong and possible solutions. Regardless, I remember you answering another one of my questions a few weeks back- thanks for sticking by and answering my questions Barmar.

Comment: Are you adding the classes in a different script from adding the user? If so, you can get the `$idUser` by querying the `users` class for the userid.